# Calculating approximate waking up times spanning 60 days instead spanning 50 days for FRSD sufferers

Tags: linear-algebra, divisibility

Free Running Sleep Disorder is a chronic and cyclic sleep disorder in which a cycle of [free running sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-running_sleep) repeats itself once in about X time (I understand that mostly once in about 60 days, depends on severity);
Unless life tasks are adjusted to the disorder, or unless the disorder is properly treated, it can have serious bad ramifications for the sufferer.

### My problem

I have created a chart to represent a *natural day-hour-minute waking up cycle* for an FRSD sufferer spanning on 50 days:

```
Day 01: Wake up at 06:00
Day 02: Wake up at 06:30
Day 03: Wake up at 07:00
Day 04: Wake up at 07:30
Day 05: Wake up at 08:00
Day 06: Wake up at 08:30
Day 07: Wake up at 09:00
Day 08: Wake up at 09:30
Day 09: Wake up at 10:00
Day 10: Wake up at 10:30

Day 11: Wake up at 11:00
Day 12: Wake up at 11:30
Day 13: Wake up at 12:00
Day 14: Wake up at 12:30
Day 15: Wake up at 13:00
Day 16: Wake up at 13:30
Day 17: Wake up at 14:00
Day 18: Wake up at 14:30
Day 19: Wake up at 15:00
Day 20: Wake up at 15:30

Day 21: Wake up at 16:00
Day 22: Wake up at 16:30
Day 23: Wake up at 17:00
Day 24: Wake up at 17:30
Day 25: Wake up at 18:00
Day 26: Wake up at 18:30
Day 27: Wake up at 19:00
Day 28: Wake up at 19:30
Day 29: Wake up at 20:00
Day 30: Wake up at 20:30

Day 31: Wake up at 21:00
Day 32: Wake up at 21:30
Day 33: Wake up at 22:00
Day 34: Wake up at 22:30
Day 35: Wake up at 23:00
Day 36: Wake up at 23:30
Day 37: Wake up at 24:00
Day 38: Wake up at 24:30
Day 39: Wake up at 01:00
Day 40: Wake up at 01:30

Day 41: Wake up at 02:00
Day 42: Wake up at 02:30
Day 43: Wake up at 03:00
Day 44: Wake up at 03:30
Day 45: Wake up at 04:00
Day 46: Wake up at 04:30
Day 47: Wake up at 05:00
Day 48: Wake up at 05:30
Day 49: Wake up at 06:00
Day 50: Wake up at 06:30
```

I need to add a sixth group to the chart to complete 6 groups representing an hour-minute span of 60 days but I don't know how to do so, maybe I lack enough knowledge in math to do the calculation for 60 days.

```
Day 51: Wake up at **:**
Day 52: Wake up at **:**
Day 53: Wake up at **:**
Day 54: Wake up at **:**
Day 55: Wake up at **:**
Day 56: Wake up at **:**
Day 57: Wake up at **:**
Day 58: Wake up at **:**
Day 59: Wake up at **:**
Day 60: Wake up at **:**
```

### My question

**How should I span the hours and minutes of approximate waking up of each day?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wake time should shift by $\frac{24 \text{ hr}}{60}=24\text{ min}$ every day. Then after 60 days, the wake time will have shifted by 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you dearly, John,